# How to install and get started with moai on Ubuntu?

Tags: moai

I am trying to install moai on Ubuntu.
I tried following this: https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/wiki/Building-MOAI-on-Ubuntu-14.10-64bit
and completed all the steps. It seemed as if everything completed. But now I don't know what to do.
How to run moai ?
I somewhere saw it was mentioned to run

```
moai main.lua
```

However I tried

```
which moai
```

without any result.
I thought that **moai** isn't in my **PATH** but I don't know which location to add to my PATH variable, because there isn't any file in **moai-dev/bin** folder of the name **moai** on my PC.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just download [moai binary release](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev/releases) which is available for linux, osx and windows. After unpacking just put moaidist/linux/moai in your PATH.